# Is std::string::replace() optimized for same length strings?

Tags: c++, optimization, replace, stdstring

Suppose, most of the time I have below scenario for replacement:

```
std::string line; // "line" contains a big string.
std::string from = "abcd";
std::string to = "xy";  // to.length() < from.length()
// replace "from" with "to" everywhere in "line"
```

Here the `string` class has to put `"xy"` and then erase 2 characters which effectively shifts all character in `line` towards left. There are so many such replacements happening throughout the life of my code.

Now coming to the real question. Below is also acceptable for me:

```
// ...
if(to.legnth() < from.length())
  to.resize(from.length(), ' ');
// now to.length() = from.length()
// replace "from" with "to" everywhere in "line"
```

Above exercise is helpful only if `replace()` is optimized for same length strings. It should be because that's trivial; but just wanted to confirm if someone has the 1st hand knowledge.
I tried browsing through Eclipse IDE into string class, but couldn't dig into so much.

Comment: If it isn't implementation-dependent, I'll be very surprised (wouldn't be the first time).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, haven't you read the heading before marking it for close ?

Comment: Seems like a legitimate question to me.  Is the function `std::string::replace()` optimized when the target (to replace) and replacement string are the same length.

Comment: A quick skim of 21.4.6.6,p11 doesn't seem to mention anything about restrictions or optimizations for same-length, so I'm going with my first assessment; implementation-dependent.

Comment: @iammilind Still relying on the title alone to make up a valid question without asking one in the question body is bad practice (though not a close or downvote reason for me in this case).

Comment: @iammilind: Why do you say I marked it for close?

Comment: Have you tried timing it? Of course benchmarks can be unreliable, but then again so can general statements about whether implementations typically perform a certain optimization. I don't believe that there are any time complexity limits in the standard to require the optimization you're after. But I'd be... disappointed with an implementation that performed a linear pass over the tail of the string to shift it left 0 places, one such pass for each time it replaces `abcd` with `xy__`.

Comment: Also, I'd slightly hope that in the case where `to` is no larger than `from`, `replace` behaves like `remove_if` in the sense that it writes in a single linear pass, with a write position that is always at or behind the read position. If so then there's very little to optimize in the "equal-size" case compared with the "smaller" case.

Comment: @SteveJessop, seems to be an agreeable point. According to the code shown by @borisbn, it seems that optimization is not needed. Rather it's taken care trivially while `"fill hole"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just look at MSVC 2008's implementation. They **do** optimize (I omit some stuff):

```
_Myt& __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL replace(size_type _Off,
    size_type _N0, const _Myt& _Right, size_type _Roff, size_type _Count)
{
    ...
        if (_Count <= _N0)
        {   // hole doesn't get larger, just copy in substring
        _Traits_helper::move_s<_Traits>(_Myptr() + _Off, _Myres - _Off,
            _Myptr() + _Roff, _Count);  // fill hole
        _Traits_helper::move_s<_Traits>(_Myptr() + _Off + _Count, _Myres - _Off - _Count,
            _Myptr() + _Off + _N0, _Nm);    // move tail down
        }
    else if (_Roff <= _Off)
        {   // hole gets larger, substring begins before hole
        _Traits_helper::move_s<_Traits>(_Myptr() + _Off + _Count, _Myres - _Off - _Count,
            _Myptr() + _Off + _N0, _Nm);    // move tail down
        _Traits_helper::move_s<_Traits>(_Myptr() + _Off, _Myres - _Off,
            _Myptr() + _Roff, _Count);  // fill hole
        }
    else if (_Off + _N0 <= _Roff)
        {   // hole gets larger, substring begins after hole
        _Traits_helper::move_s<_Traits>(_Myptr() + _Off + _Count, _Myres - _Off - _Count,
            _Myptr() + _Off + _N0, _Nm);    // move tail down
        _Traits_helper::move_s<_Traits>(_Myptr() + _Off, _Myres - _Off,
            _Myptr() + (_Roff + _Count - _N0), _Count); // fill hole
        }
    else
        {   // hole gets larger, substring begins in hole
        _Traits_helper::move_s<_Traits>(_Myptr() + _Off, _Myres - _Off,
            _Myptr() + _Roff, _N0); // fill old hole
        _Traits_helper::move_s<_Traits>(_Myptr() + _Off + _Count, _Myres - _Off - _Count,
            _Myptr() + _Off + _N0, _Nm);    // move tail down
        _Traits_helper::move_s<_Traits>(_Myptr() + _Off + _N0, _Myres - _Off - _N0, _Myptr() + _Roff + _Count,
            _Count - _N0);  // fill rest of new hole
        }
        ...
    }
```

Take an attantion, that the case when new length is smaller and the case when lengths are equal are similar.

**Edit**: It can be concluded that in the case of same length strings after copying data, total "0" characters/holes have to be moved/filled (i.e. no movement). Thus no optimization is really needed, but it's taken care trivially.