# To replace one char by a higher amount of chars within a string, without deleting other letters in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, str-replace, stdstring

I want to replace character 'ü' in a string if found in it. My code replaces `ü`, but also deleting other letters in the string.

```
 if (word.find('ü') != string::npos) 
 {
     word.replace(word.find('ü'), 'ü', "ue");
 }
```

Comment: Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030626/replace-char-in-string-with-some-string-inplace) asks something similar.

Comment: `'ü'` as character constant will only work with single byte encoding (i.e. _not_ UTF-8). You should use the string constant `"ü"` instead. This will also work with UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the position of `ü`, starting from index `0` until end of the string and whenever you find, replace it with `ue` using the information of both position where you found and the length of the string you would like to find in the given string.

Something like follows: [**SEE LIVE HERE**](https://www.ideone.com/deQVFN)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>

int main()
{
   std::string word("Herr Müller ist ein König.");

   std::string findThis = "ü";
   std::string replaceWith = "ue";

   std::size_t pos = 0;
   while ((pos = word.find(findThis, pos)) != std::string::npos)
   {
      word.replace(pos, findThis.length(), replaceWith);
      pos += replaceWith.length();
   }

   std::cout << word << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Herr Mueller ist ein König.
```

Comment: What is a Kuenig? :)

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow 'König' is the german word for king.

Comment: If it was written with "ö", it would have meant king in German :) But anyway, thank you JeJo!

Comment: I know that König is king. I was commenting on the fact that he replaced ö with ue. Fixed now in the answer.

Comment: This would be O(n^2) in general? Though in this particular case it doesn't change the length in bytes of the string because ASCII characters only take one byte in UTF-8 (see https://www.ideone.com/HnRErj). A marginally smart .replace() should be able to ensure O(n) in this case, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321174/is-stdstringreplace-optimized-for-same-length-strings

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by your solution is a generalised case. With n as the combined length of the input and output strings, in the general case your solution provides O(n^2) performance. It would be possible to get O(n) performance in the general case, I presume boost::replace_all does this.

Comment: `find()` should take a total of O(n) time, but `replace()` presumably takes O(n) time if it has to move the remainder of the string, and you call it up to n times, so O(n*n) time in total.

Answer (score 2):

Not a one-liner, but `erase` followed by `insert` is clear enough.

```
size_t x = word.find('ü');
while (x != string::npos)
    {
    word.erase(x, 1);
    word.insert(x, "ue");
    x = word.find('ü');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If using boost is an option you can do something like this

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string str("Herr Müller ist ein König.");
    boost::replace_all(str, "ü", "ue");
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Wow, thats looks great, thanks :) I think i will use this one in future.